# StanfordCoreNLP object creation error

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-classification, stanford-nlp

I am facing this issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)

Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.ExtractorDistsim; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 2
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1630)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1714)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readExtractors(MaxentTagger.java:622)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:868)
... 23 more
```

at code line

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref, sentiment");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Note : I have put the stanford core nlp latest jar file but it didn't work and even tried explicitly adding stanford nlp pos tagger jar file but it didn't work and even tried adding the models jar file but didn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Can you post the exact command you used to run the program? This error is caused by the model jar not being in your classpath.

Comment: @GaborAngeli I am not running it on command line, i am using IntelliJ Idea. I have added the jar files -> 1. stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar 2. stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar

Comment: @GaborAngeli i have edited the issue stack trace of the exception please check......

Comment: @GaborAngeli thanks for the help the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever encounters this problem i would suggest them to visit https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP and download the LATEST model files from there it will mostly solve the issue.